# iOS 8 Safari and jQuery-minicolor: cannot parse response

Tags: jquery, ios, css, mobile-safari

I want to use `jQuery-minicolor` and `angular-minicolor` for a simple colorpicker. Everything is fine in most cases, except for when visiting the website with iOS Safari: in the debug mode, I can see there is an error:

> [Error] Failed to load resource: cannot parse response (jquery.minicolors.css, line 0)

which points to the `.css` file on my server (which was obtained from https://github.com/claviska/jquery-minicolors/blob/master/jquery.minicolors.css).

I wonder if this can be fixed?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: For me, this was a problem with my server. I fixed it by loading my file from a CDN instead of loading a local copy. Still have no idea what causes this, though.