# iOS web app "failed to parse response"

Tags: javascript, html, ios, apache, cellular-network

My web app does a simple load of a JavaScript file using `<script type="text/javascript" src="path_to_file.js"></script>`. On my iOS devices, I see a couple issues **only** when visiting my web app over cellular data, which is very strange to me.

Over cellular data, the *first* time I visit the page, I see the error:

```
Failed to load resource: cannot decode raw data
```

The internet seems to think this issue is related to compression of some sort, but that's clearly not relevant; I'm doing nothing related to compression with any files.

All subsequent times I visit the page, my devices consistently show an error in the console:

```
Failed to load resource: cannot parse response
```

in reference to loading the `vis.min.js` file. The file is 610 KB, which is large for a JavaScript file but smaller than many images, so I don't think that's the issue. Visiting [the file](http://luke.deentaylor.com/wikipedia/libraries/vis/vis.min.js) manually I have no problem.

If I refresh the page 10-20 times, I can get it to work on only one of those tries, and this issue *never* appears over Wi-Fi.

I debug this issue by turning off wifi on my phone, and then by connecting it to my Mac in order to use the development tools. Looking at the "Network" page, I can see that this file takes more than 5 seconds to load. Other similarly sized files took less than half a second to load.

[image: Slow loading]

Looking online, I wasn't able to find anything about the specific error "could not parse response," besides [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29664296/ios-8-safari-and-jquery-minicolor-cannot-parse-response) (almost a year old). I thought I'd post a new, much more detailed question, in hope of getting a response.

So, **what is the meaning of these errors, what causes them, and why do they only occur over cellular data? Most importantly, how can I fix them?**

The page in question is http://luke.deentaylor.com/wikipedia/, if anyone would like to try to reproduce the issues.

Comment: Could you post this js file? or show me a demo reproduced this situation?

Comment: The JS file is the minified file distributed with [vis.js](http://visjs.org). The copy I'm reading from is at http://luke.deentaylor.com/wikipedia/libraries/vis/vis.min.js

Comment: Have you tried to use http://luke.deentaylor.com/wikipedia/libraries/vis/vis.min.js instead `./libraries/vis/vis.min.js`

Comment: No. Do you think that would make a difference? It's not saying it can't find the file... I'll certainly try that though.

Comment: @ElfSundae sorry, no luck.

Comment: The js file loaded fine on my iPhone in cellular network. Let webview load your js file directly, what will happen?

Comment: @ElfSundae First off, what carrier are you using? Second, this web app is through safari, not through a webview in Objective-C. Third, I already mentioned that I can visit the problem without an issue. Can you try visiting [the app in question](http://luke.deentaylor.com/wikipedia/) and see if entering text and pressing "Go" does anything over cellular? If the screen still says the informational text, the above is the error it throws.

Comment: I tested on my iPhone Safari, it woks well, via China Telecom 4G and 3G.

Comment: Huh. I can't get it to work on AT&T LTE without refreshing more than 20 times. Can you refresh it, and see if it still works after you've refreshed a few times?

Comment: Yes, I refreshed serval times. I suggest you check the details of data transmission with tcpdump or wireshark.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing my local files with CDN-hosted copies seemed to fix it. I assume this was a problem with DigitalOcean.

Answer (score 1):

I came across this same problem. For me the solution was to set the header/metadata Content-Type of that gzip file to "text/javascript"